# What are the implications of adding "./" to relative symbolic links?

Tags: files, filesystems, filenames, symlink, ln

I noticed that when I create relative symbolic links, starting the source path with `./` keeps it that way and starting with an alphanumeric character keeps it that way, despite them both meaning the same thing. Both kinds act identically in every case I can think of, but there must be a reason why the developers chose to add this seemingly unnecessary redundancy; perhaps there are edge cases where one would behave differently from the other.

Comment: Why do you think anybody had to add any redundancy? This could simply be a result of how pathname resolution works in the first place.

Comment: @muru Good point. But my more general question remains.

Comment: This isn't redundancy. This is simply "do exactly what the user told us to do, and don't try to second-guess them by looking for redundancies which will only slow down the program 99.999% of the time it's run."

Comment: There must at least be compatibility implications.

Comment: Of course, there's the case you sidestepped by saying "alphanumeric character" - filenames beginning with a `-` are significantly different in behaviour

Comment: Why should the developers put in a check to see if you linked `./foo/bar` instead of `foo/bar`? The relative path is the same so should they second-guess your intent?

Comment: @ATLief, you could also use `././somefile`, or `./././somefile`. The `./` just means to go to the current directory, so that's what follows. Now, if you're asking why the `.` exists for "this directory", that's different. (And probably answered somewhere online, not that I can find it right now.) Similarly, if the link is known to be in `dir`, the link could contain `../dir/somefile` with the same effect as `./somefile`, or just `somefile`. But that requires extra information.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a symbolic link [only stores the target as a string](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/symlink.html), no attempt is made to resolve the link at all. There are several reasons for this; one is that a symbolic link can be created pointing to a file which may exist later (because it will be created later, or because it will appear later, *e.g.* through a new mounted file system); another is that symbolic links can be used to reference data which isn’t a file at all (on Linux, look at the links under `/proc/*/fd` — you’ll see some pointing to pipes, sockets, deleted files etc.).

The target of a symbolic link is explicitly specified to be a string, stored as-is. It is only interpreted when a program attempts to open the symbolic link as if it’s a file.